# How Do I destroy (unset) a variable in a different class?

Tags: php

Is there anyway I can unset (and set a new value) for a variable in a core class of a script without touching the core code?

This is how the value of the variable set in the class:

```
class MyClass {
    var $myvar = 'value';
    ...
    ...
}
```

I tried this, but didn't worked;

```
function unset_myvar($myvar) {
    unset($myvar);
    $myvar = 'newvalue';

    return $myvar;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Using keyword var is a PHP4 implementation!

Comment: What's the point of unsetting and reinitializing the property, though? Why not just overwrite its value?

Comment: Seems like a great idea only if I can do that without editing that class. Any way to do that? @RainFromHeaven ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code prints the value which was assigned , unsets the variable and then sets a new value to the variable.

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    var $myvar = 'value';

    public function dispvar()
    {
        echo $this->myvar;
    }

    public function destroyvar()
    {
        unset($this->myvar);
    }

    public function setvar($param)
    {
        $this->myvar=$param;
    }

}

$a = new MyClass();
$a->dispvar(); //"prints" value
$a->destroyvar();
$a->dispvar(); //"prints" nothing !!
$a->setvar('blabla');
$a->dispvar(); //"prints" blabla
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/99873)

Comment: would `$a->myvar = 'newvalue'` work or does the visibility of a variable default to protected/private?

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
$myvar = 'newvalue';
```

you are looking for

```
$this->myvar = 'newvalue';
```

You are asking elementary question, so I suggest instead of just copying lines from my answer, you now head to PHP.net and read manual about PHP fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 class MyClass {
        var $myvar = 'value';

        function unset_myvar($myvar) {
           unset($this->myvar);
           $this->myvar = $myvar;

          return $this->myvar;
        }
    }
```

So, now you can creat and object and unset variable and set another value to it:

```
$obj = MyClass ();
$obj = unset_myvar('someValue');
```

Comment: Now it used, as example

Answer (score 0):

**Simply:**

```
class MyClass {
    public $myvar = 'value';
    ...
    ...
}

$obj = new MyClass();
unset($obj->myvar);
```